# Layout problems with Twitter Bootstrap/Wordpress Integration

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running into this puzzling problem with laying out the headers and footers appropriately inside the Wordpress environment.  Basically, I originally developed my web pages using Twitter bootstrap so my header and footer part of the page are laid out nicely.  However, now that I'm slowly integrating the twitter bootstrap pages into Wordpress environment and this is the output I see.

**Header**

[image: Header]

**Footer**

[image: Footer]

I notice there's extra white space for the header and footer portions of the web page.  This never happened before in my original work on a single html file.  But when integrating them using Wordpress platform such as their own css, .php files etc, etc, the layout's completely different?

Has anybody experienced with this type of problem when integrating Twitter Bootstrap inside Wordpress environment?  Can someone please advise me what do I need to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind about it.

I've found out the reason.

I realised there's a extra padding on top and the bottom of the body element of the document.  Hence for the white space.

I fixed up in the css and now the extra white space is gone!!